# Using Terraform Modules

Tags: azure, terraform, azureportal, infrastructure-as-code, terraform-modules

We're provisioning a Landing Zone in Azure and will predominantly use the following:

1. Terraform as our IaC.
2. Azure Pipelines for provisioning the required Azure resources.

As we will be provisioning across multiple environments - Dev, Test and Prod, we've identified a modular approach to be the preferred option for our Terraform code. I'd therefore like a very basic example of how I can put together a Terraform module for 3 Resource Groups deployed across all three environments - Dev, Test and Prod.

Hopefully, I can then adopt the same concept to provision other resources in a modular manner.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to accomplish this. If you are using Terraform's Cloud backend for state management I would recommend looking at [Terraform Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html).

Alternatively, we work with multiple environments with internal modules quite a bit here. The way we achieved it:

```
/
README.md
main.tf
variables.tf
environments/
../dev/
....terraform.tfvars
```

This allows you to have X amount of variables, and with CI you can just point to these differnet variables per environment files to separate things out by specifying these files. We use Gitlab CI/CD and Gitlab's backend for state:

```
build:
  stage: build
  interruptible: true
  script:
    - gitlab-terraform plan -var-file=$TFVARS_DIR/terraform.tfvars
    - gitlab-terraform plan-json
```

`main.tf` will include modules or we can break it out once it goes > 100 lines.

Comment: Tristanvvatson, your feedback is excellent and much appreciated. I think that proposed source structure (split across the various environments) works great and we've implemented something similar with dedicated folders for dev, test and prod. What is however the big challenge now is how we can configure the pipeline tasks for each of our 3 Azure Release Pipeline stages (Dev, Test and Prod) to call/consume their dedicated *.tfvars file. Any suggestion?

Comment: @hitman126 - We pass two tfvar files - one standard and one secret. We can expand secrets that we manage at Gitlab CI/CD level and depends on the user's permissions. For example, if we wanted to store the Database password, we could do that a secret variable, then using `gettext` - we evaluate a template file and interpolate the required variables to create a new file before we run next steps.

We do templating via Anchors in YAML, but we have 3 different distinct environment directories. The rest of the file path is the same, and as Gitlab has Environments as a concept.

Comment: '@tristanvvatson' appreciate your assistance.